# Jackson default JsonView for Serialization

Tags: json, spring, jackson, resteasy

Is there a way to define which JsonView is used by default when serializing an object?

I have three views, DefaultView, UserView, and AdminView. Right now if I do not specifically set a view to use, it will include *all* fields from Default, User, and Admin views.

I would like it to only include fields from DefaultView unless I explicitly mark my rest endpoint with @JsonView(UserView.class/AdminView.class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view used for serialization can be set with the following code:

```
objectMapper.setConfig(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(DefaultView.class));
```

I ended up removing DefaultView. Any fields that belonged to a specialized view I continued to annotate with @JsonView(UserView.class/AdminView.class). Any fields I didn't ever want serialized I marked as @JsonIgnore.

I utilized the following ObjectMapper config to get my desired results:

```
@Provider
public class JacksonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonContextResolver() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setConfig(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(Object.class)); 
        objectMapper.enable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);            
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```